Proving asymptotic normality when using an estimator to the asymptotic variance
${\hat{V_n}}$ and ${V_n}$ both sequences of symmetric positive definite $k \times k $ random matrices, I am given that:
$$||V_n^{-1/2}\hat{V_n}V_n^{-1/2}-I_k||\rightarrow^p0 \qquad V_n^{-1/2}(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta)\rightarrow^dN(0,I_k)$$
Where $\hat{\theta}_n$ is a sequence of random $k$ vectors. I am trying to prove that $\hat{V_n}^{-1/2}(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta)\rightarrow^dN(0,I_k)$.
Attempt 1: Since $V_n^{-1/2}\hat{V_n}V_n^{-1/2}\rightarrow^pI_k$, I have by the Cramer Wold Theorem and CMT that:
$$(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta)^T\hat{V_n}^{-1/2}\hat{V_n}^{-1/2}(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta) = [(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta)^T V_n^{-1/2}]V_n^{1/2}\hat{V_n}^{-1}V_n^{1/2}[V_n^{-1/2}(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta)]\rightarrow^dZ^TZ$$
With $Z\sim N(0,I_k)$. I am not sure where to proceed from here as this clearly does not imply that $\hat{V_n}^{-1/2}(\hat{\theta_n}-\theta)\rightarrow^dN(0,I_k)$.
Attempt 2: Since $(\hat{V_n}^{1/2}V_n^{-1/2})^T(\hat{V_n}^{1/2}V_n^{-1/2})=V_n^{-1/2}\hat{V_n}V_n^{-1/2}\rightarrow^pI_k$, I was thinking that if I could prove that $\hat{V_n}^{1/2}V_n^{-1/2}$ was upper/lower triangular, then I could prove $\hat{V_n}^{1/2}V_n^{-1/2}\rightarrow^d I_k$ by exploiting that the Cholesky decomposition defines a continuous mapping from the set of symmetric positive definite matrices ($V_n^{-1/2}\hat{V_n}V_n^{-1/2}$ is symmetric positive definite) to the set of upper triangular matrices. But I am not sure how.
This is exercise 93 CH5 of Jun Shao's Mathematical Statistics.

Two missing information: 1) What is the matrix norm used in the first claim? 2) How does the sequence $\hat{\theta_n}$ converge to $\theta$ in the second claim?
